# How can I comment out snmpmibd and snmpd in rc.tcpip in AIX using sed?

Tags: sed, scripting

I need to comment out an entry in rc.tcpip file inside /etc

> # Start up the snmpmibd daemon
>    start /usr/sbin/snmpmibd "$src_running"
>
> # Start up the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) daemon
>    start /usr/sbin/snmpd "$src_running"

How do I comment these lines using `sed`?

Comment: What makes those lines unique? We need to know something that _only_ those lines contain. Would `snmp` be unique for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comment out lines that start with `start /usr/sbin/snmpmibd`, use the `s` command with a pattern using the `^` anchor and `#` in the replacement text, plus `&` which stands for the replaced text. You can either match the two lines separately, or notice that `snmpd` is `snmpmibd` with `mib` omitted (concision at the expense of clarity)¹ and use `snmp\(mib\)\{0,1\}d`. Since the pattern contains a slash, use another character as the delimiter, such as `!`. Since `sed` is a filter, you'll need to write the output to a new file, then move the new file into place (redirecting the output of `sed` to the same file as the input wouldn't work: it would first erase the old file, then start reading from the now-empty file)².

```
sed -e 's!^start /usr/sbin/snmpmibd !#&!' -e 's!^start /usr/sbin/snmpmibd !#&!' </etc/rc.tcpip >/etc/rc.tcpip.new
mv /etc/rc.tcpip.new /etc/rc.tcpip
```

To edit a file in place, you can use [ed](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fed.htm) instead of sed.

```
ed -s /etc/rc.tcpip <<'EOF'
g!^start /usr/sbin/snmpd ! s/^/#/
g!^start /usr/sbin/snmpmibd ! s/^/#/
w
q
EOF
```

¹  <sub>AIX doesn't have `\?` or `\|` operators, only started BRE, so `\(snmpmibd\|snmpd\)` won't work.</sub> 
²  <sub>AIX sed doesn't have `-i`, that's a GNU extension.</sub>

Comment: not necessary to add the 2 section of action in sed, just separe this with a `;` and -e is not mandatory in case of AIX sed :-)

Comment: My thanks to you both @Gilles and @NeronLeVelu!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gilles for the remark on AIX sed not allowing -i

to comment lines

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[^#]/#&/' /etc/rc.tcpip > /tmp/rc.tcpip
cat /tmp/rc.tcpip /etc/rc.tcpip
rm /tmp/rc.tcpip
```

a filter on line to select could be done adding `/yourRegExFilterPattern/` before the `s` like :

```
sed '/start/ s/^[[:space:]]*[^#]/#&/' /etc/rc.tcpip > /tmp/rc.tcpip
cat /tmp/rc.tcpip /etc/rc.tcpip
rm /tmp/rc.tcpip
```

or, more efficient but less readable on complex filter (not the case here with a simple `start`)

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*start/#&/' /etc/rc.tcpip > /tmp/rc.tcpip
cat /tmp/rc.tcpip /etc/rc.tcpip
rm /tmp/rc.tcpip
```

to uncomment lines (need the filter directly pattern to avoid uncommenting real comments)

```
sed '/YourSelectionPattern/ s/^\(^[[:space:]]*\)#/\1/' /etc/rc.tcpip > /tmp/rc.tcpip
cat /tmp/rc.tcpip /etc/rc.tcpip
rm /tmp/rc.tcpip
```

You may need extra rights to modify this file if you are not root, so a `sudo` is the key.

I also recommend making a backup copy of `/etc/rc.tcpip` before just in case.

Comment: `sed -i` is a GNU extension, not present on AIX.

Comment: @Gilles: sorry I forget the AIX from the title and no reference in request (+1 on your remark). Make the correction in my post

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/rc.tcpip`, comment out the `snmpd` entry by running command:

```
chrctcp -d snmpd
```